# How to show pandas data on web page with d3 style graphs?

Tags: python, django, d3.js, pandas, vincent

I have quite a few analysis routines in python with pandas. I would like to get started with putting these online perhaps with d3js. I'm a complete newbie. A few searches revealed packages such as vincent. There seems to be python web development with django. Should I be converting my scientific scripts into django somehow? Do I need to combine these together somehow with vincent and django? Does anyone know about any tutorials for this topic? I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to get started and what packages to use.

Comment: You can just pandas as part of your python script to export data that can be then displayed with d3.js.

Answer (score 4):

Django isn't a bad way to go if you are looking to create a full blown web application. Pandas allows you to pass DataFrame and Series data in JSON format which can then be interpreted and displayed using D3 for example.

Some potentially useful links to look at include:

- [django-nvd3](https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3)
- [django-rest-pandas](https://github.com/wq/django-rest-pandas)

Some good Django tutorials also include:

- [Tango with Django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/)
- [Django Project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/)